# How to find a string/word in a string using Powershell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, powershell, find

I know this sounds like a simple question but nothing I have tried works.

I have to compare data from SQL database to a text file. I have to check if the PartNumber(PartNo), Revision(Rev), and Version(Ver) exist in the first line of the text file.
The issue is that for some PartNo the script gives incorrect results. I can see the PartNo is the same but it shows that it is not a match. I have no issues matching the Rev and Ver.

There are two PartNo in particular that don't match(when they should) and they are C29254 and 1-1-25B17. There are other PartNo that are in alphanumeric form but they match. For example, D73874 matches. I don't know what is about these two parts that is not working out.

I have checked the data type of the values that I get from the database and it is a string. The first line from my text file is also a string.

This is what I have tried so far:

`If($EiaContent -Contains "$partNo"))`   None of the parts match(when some should)
`If($EiaContent -Like $partNo)`         None of the parts match(when some should)
`If($EiaContent -Like "*$partNo*")`     C29254, 1-1-25B17 Do not match(when they should)
`If($EiaContent -match $partNo)`       C29254, 1-1-25B17 Do not match(when they should)
`If($EiaContent -match "$partNo")`     C29254, 1-1-25B17 Do not match(when they should)
`If($EiaContent | Select-String -Pattern $partNo -SimpleMatch)`   C29254, 1-1-25B17 Do not match(when they should)
`If($EiaContent | Select-String -Pattern $partNo)`  C29254, 1-1-25B17 Do not match(when they should)
`If($EiaContent | Select-Object $partNo )` All parts match(when some shouldn't)
The code below is part of a long block that does other stuff so I am just posting the part related to the issue.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.
Code:

```
    #Get the content (first line)of each .EIA file in the folder.
    $EiaContent=(Get-Content $aidLibPathFolder\$folderName\$fileName  -TotalCount 1)
    Write-host $EiaContent
    
    #Sql query to get the Part Number
    $partNoQuery = "SELECT  [PartNo] FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vMADL_EngParts]  Where   MAFN=$firstPartTrimmed"
    $partNoSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $partNoQuery
    $partNo  = $partNoSql.PartNo.ToString()
    $partNo.GetType().Name
    write-host $partNo -ForegroundColor Magenta
    
    ##Find PartNo##
    If($EiaContent | Select-Object $partNo ){
    Write-Host "Part Matches"
    }
    Else{
    Write-Host "Part Does Not Match"
    }
    
   #Sql query to get the Revs
    $revQuery = "SELECT  [MA_Rev] As Rev FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[MADL_EngParts]  Where MAFN=$firstPartTrimmed"
    $revSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $revQuery
    $rev = "REV" + " "+ $revSql.Rev
    $rev.GetType().Name
    write-host $rev -ForegroundColor Red
    If($EiaContent -like "*$rev*"){
    Write-Host "Rev Matches"
    }
    Else{
    Write-Host "Rev Does not Match"
    } 
    Write-Host $version -BackgroundColor Black
    If($EiaContent -like "*$version*"){
    Write-Host "Version Matches"
    }
    Else{
    Write-Host "Version Does Not Match"
    } 
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: could you please indent the code, it is so unreadable

Comment: and why are you trying to find the rev number if sql can do it for you

Comment: @nbk I think you didn't read the question properly. I have to compare the data, dude. I need to check if Rev,PartNo, and Ver are correct in the file. I get the PartNo and Rev from the db and Ver from somewhere else then check if they are the same in the text file.

Comment: You might have spaces / non-printing characters embedded in your file or your sql data. Try something like ```write-host “eia content = ‘$EiaContent’ - $($EiaContent.Length)”``` and make sure the length matches what you expect it to be. Try the same thing with other string variables as well and look for any discrepancies.

Comment: If that doesn’t find anything you can try comparing the character bytes - e.g. ```write-host ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($PartNo))```. For ```C29254``` this gives ```67 50 57 50 53 52```.

Comment: @mclayton Thanks for the reply. You were right about the extra characters. `$PartNo.Lenght` shows as 28 instead of 6 for `C29254`. This is the one I get from SQL. Is there is any way to eliminate the extra space in the SQL query?

Comment: It depends on what the extra characters are. If they’re space chars you can use ```Trim()```, but dumping out the bytes per my second comment ^^^ will help with working out what to do to normalise the data…

Comment: Np. You’ve possibly got fixed width columns in your database so values are getting padded with spaces, or maybe that specific record somehow got glitched when it was entered.